# Pre-deployment conditions : deploy into prod if one the test deployment is success

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

Based on latest build I want to deploy one of the test environments(There are many test environments). Will choose test environment during the release then deploy into preProd and PRod if test deployment is success.

How to add Pre-deployment conditions if one of the deployment is success in the triggers?

Below one is the best example for my scenario. Deployment to the Production stage occurs if one of QA and Pre-prod stages are successful. Like or conditions.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=vsts#parallel-forked-and-joined-deployments
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking we don't recommend that trigger the production deployment even if some of the test deployments are failed.

If you still want to do that, you could use the [a gate for a stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=vsts#define-a-gate-for-a-stage). It allows us to customized or trigger conditions by our self. Based on my experience, you could invoke REST API or Invoke Azure Function to implement the logic by yourself.

[image]

Comment: I didn't read the question as wanting to deploy prod on a prior stage failure.  I read it more as they have a pool of test environments, they deploy to a single test from that pool, and if that is successful deploy to production.